# Prove that $\cos2\theta−\sqrt{3}\sin2\theta \equiv2 \cos (2\theta+\pi/3 )\equiv−2\sin(2\theta−\pi/6)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Going from $2\cos(2\theta+\pi/3)$ to $\cos2\theta−\sqrt{3}\sin2\theta$ is simple enough, however I'm stuck on going from $2\cos(2\theta+\pi/3)$ to $−2\sin(2\theta−\pi /6)$. How do i do this?

Comment: $\cos w=\sin(\pi/2-w)$

Comment: We usually just use $=$ for identities, by the way. $\equiv$ is used for something else entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the identities for the sine and cosine of the sum or difference of two angles:

$$\begin{align*}
\sin\left(2\theta-\frac{\pi}6\right)&=\sin2\theta\cos\frac{\pi}6-\cos2\theta\sin\frac{\pi}6\\
&=\frac{\sqrt3}2\sin2\theta-\frac12\cos2\theta\;,
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
\cos\left(2\theta+\frac{\pi}3\right)&=\cos2\theta\cos\frac{\pi}3-\sin2\theta\sin\frac{\pi}3\\&=\frac12\cos2\theta-\frac{\sqrt3}2\sin2\theta\;.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

First, let's recap:
$\sin{\pi\over3}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\cos{\pi\over3}=\frac12$

$\sin{\pi\over6}=\frac12$

$\cos{\pi\over6}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$


**Let's rock 'n roll!**

**Solution 1:**
Going from $\cos2\theta−\sqrt{3}\sin2\theta$ to $2\cos\left(2\theta+\frac\pi3\right)$.
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\cos2\theta−\sqrt{3}\sin2\theta&=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta-\sqrt{3}\cdot2\sin\theta\cos\theta\\
&=2\cdot\frac12\left(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta-\sqrt{3}\cdot2\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)\\
&=2\left(\frac12\left(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)-\frac12\sqrt{3}\cdot2\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)\\
&=2\left(\left(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)\cos\frac{\pi}{3}-2\sin\theta\cos\theta\sin\frac\pi3\right)\\
&=2\left(\cos2\theta\cos\frac\pi3-\sin2\theta\sin\frac\pi3\right)\\
&=2\cos\left(2\theta+\frac\pi3\right)
\end{align}
$$
**Solution 2:**
Going from $\cos2\theta−\sqrt{3}\sin2\theta$ to $\sin(2\theta−\frac\pi6)$.
$$
\begin{align}
\cos2\theta−\sqrt{3}\sin2\theta&=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta-\sqrt{3}\cdot2\sin\theta\cos\theta\\
&=-2\cdot\left(-\frac12\right)\left(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta-\sqrt{3}\cdot2\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)\\
&=-2\left(\left(-\frac12\right)\left(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)-\left(-\frac12\right)\left(\sqrt{3}\cdot2\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)\right)\\
&=-2\left(\left(-\frac12\right)\left(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)-\left(-\frac12\sqrt{3}\right)\left(2\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)\right)\\
&=-2\left(-\sin\frac\pi6\left(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)-\left(-\cos\frac\pi6\right)\left(\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)\right)\\
&=-2\left(-\sin\frac\pi6\left(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)+\cos\frac\pi6\left(2\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)\right)\\
&=-2\left(\cos\frac\pi6\left(2\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)-\sin\frac\pi6\left(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)\right)\\
&=-2\left(\cos\frac\pi6\sin2\theta-\sin\frac\pi6\cos2\theta\right)\\
&=-2\left(\sin2\theta\cos\frac\pi6-\cos2\theta\sin\frac\pi6\right)\\
&=-2\sin\left(2\theta-\frac\pi6\right)
\end{align}
$$
I hope this helps.